# Live-refresh breaks stack snippet buttons

Tags: bug, stack-snippets, live-refresh

If there is already a duplicate of this bug, I was unable to find it.

[image: Bug example]

Anyway, the bug report:

If a post has a stack snippet embedded in it, and it is edited and the live-refresh 'button' clicked, the snippet code remains but the 'run' and other snippet-related buttons disappear.

I have so far only experienced this bug on others' posts.  Refreshing fixes the lack of buttons.